# Directory structure: simple application frontend/backend in pure Javascript/PHP (no framework, or CMS)

Tags: php, directory, structure, private, public

I am working on a basic web application with a single-page frontend written in pure HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript. It is not based on any framework.

The frontend has a form that sends a HTTP POST request to a backend that is written in PHP, and processes the data. The "entrypoint" of the backend is a `app.php` file.

Currently my simplified directory structure is:

```
html_public/
     index.html
     js/
     css/
     backend/
         app.php
         php/
            otherfiles.php
```

I have set a `.htaccess` file in the `backend/` directory to limit access to the `app.php` file from the HTTP server.

I am not sure whether this is a good directory structure. I have read that it would be a better option, for security reasons, to have my `backend/` directory out of the `html_public/` directory:

```
backend/
     app.php
     php/
         otherfiles.php
     html_public/
          index.html
          js/
          css/
```

Is it a better structure? But in this case, how can my frontend `index.html` can access my file `app.php`?

Any advice would be appreciated. Most of the related messages I have found are about web sites built with frameworks, and are not really relevant here.

Comment: All files that the client needs to access should to be under the document root. If you have one single entry point file for all your PHP, you can expose that file and put all other files it includes outside. But at the end of the day, your app will be as secure as you write it, regardless of folder structure. There isn't really "one way" of doing this, which makes the question a bit off-topic (since the answers will mostly be opinions). You can write a secure app with everything inside the doc root, and you can write an insecure app with everything outside of the doc root.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are right: I decided to keep my original directory structure, that should do the job.